# Can't remap to <C-)>

Tags: key-bindings

I'm using a French keyboard, and `<C-]>` to access to a tag definition is cumbersome. You need `AltGr+]` to access the `]` character, so the whole thing is 3 keys pressed at the same time: `Ctrl+AltGr+]`.

I want to remap it to `Ctrl+)`, because `)` and `]` are on the same key, but `)` is accessible directly. This is what I tried:

```
nnoremap <C-)> <C-]>
```

This doesn't work. The cursor moves as if I had just pressed `)`. Any idea on why it doesn't work, or how I could debug that?

Comment: The keycode terminals generate for `C-(` is the same of `(`. [The reason](https://bestasciitable.com/) and [how to do solve your problem with XTerm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631241).

Comment: https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm using gnome-terminal, not xterm, but I don't know if there's a way to use some extended mappings there.

Comment: No, I'm afraid Gnome-terminal does not have advanced features. Xterm may look crappy at first, but it has many, many customizable features, including the keycodes it sends in response to key presses.